# sudo from end of command

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I'm looking for a way to sudo from the end of a command either via writing a function and calling an alias to it or piping something at the end of a command.

Yes, I know I could just backup and type in sudo. Yes, I know I could just run it and then sudo !!. I am just too lazy.

If I could just write a little function to let me do something like:

```
yum -y install _____ | magic-sudo
```

Help me make `magic-sudo` a reality, I know there are enough lazy coders out there that want this to exist.

Comment: There's no way to do this. The pipe sends the OUTPUT of `yum` to `magic-sudo`, but I assume you want to execute the `yum` command itself with `sudo`.

Comment: Bash would interpret the above command  (assuming it were real) by executing yum and then taking the output of yum and using it as input for magic-sudo.  Therefore, yum would already complain about not having root privileges before reaching magic-sudo.  I think Bash would rule out this command.  Use the Home key and just type sudo.

Comment: What do lazy coders have to do with this? `sudo blah` is fewer keystrokes then `blah | magic-sudo`

Comment: `blah<enter>sudo !!` and `blah<home>sudo ` are both fewer keystrokes than `blah | magic-sudo` as well.

Comment: woooow, I'm dumb. I didn't know CTRL+A existed and I just wasn't thinking before I posted. Thanks to all those that responded so quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<CTRL-A>sudo<SPACE>
```

Go to the beginning of the line and insert `sudo` there.  This is all done with keystrokes, so any difference from typing `| magic-sudo` is superficial.

Answer (score 0):

you could just do something like

```
echo yum -y install blahblah | sudo bash
```

it would do the trick

Comment: And the OP will ask how to echo yum without backspacing, like `yum -y install blahblahbla | sudo bash | magic-echo`. :P